# Polynomial modulus in Quotient Ring

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

I have a ring $R=\Bbb Z[x]/(x^m+1)$ with $m$ some power of two and a polynomial $g \in R$, which has relatively small coefficients and some other properties that I believe to be irrelevant for this question. Lastly I have an $a \in \Bbb Z$.

I would like to reduce $a$ modulo $(g)$ to create a small polynomial $\hat a = a\mod g$ in $R$. So far I am simply assuming that $\hat a = a$, because that seems to be trivially correct, but unfortunately I am running into some trouble with this assumption later on in the construction that I am trying to implement. Thus now I am wondering if there is a different way of computing a polynomial in $R$ which is congruent to $a\mod g$. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Background: These computations are necessary when implementing the Multilinear Jigsaw Puzzles that are specified in [this paper](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/451.pdf) on page 31+.

Comment: If (a representative) $g$ is coprime to $x^m+1$, then $pg+q(x^m+1)=:d\in\mathbb Z$ for some polynomials $p,q\in\mathbb Z[x]$; in that case is $\tilde a$ can be chosen to be an constant polynomial $<d$. If $g$ divides $x^m+1$, then all we can do is reduce $a$ to degree $<m$. In the general case, I guess that combinig these results via the Chinese rRemainder Theorem gives what you want?

Comment: $a$ is already of degree $0$ as it is an element of $\Bbb Z$. Basically I am trying to find some polynomial of degree d: $0 < d < m$.
Oh and since you mentioned that it might make a difference if $g$ is coprime to $x^m+1$, one of the properties that I left out is: $|R/(g)| = p$ where p is prime. Not sure if that makes the two polynomials coprime though.